# how to find a regex pattern inside a regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have some text like the following:

```
between [... between (...)] and (...) as ...
```

with the regex

```
between\s+(.+?)\s+and\s+(.+?)\s+as
```

I am trying to capture what are inside two pairs of parentheses, i.e., the contents bounded by `between` and `and`. However I am stuck in that it always returns content in the square brackets and the second pair of parentheses.

EDIT:

for example if the text is:

```
between foo whatever between bar and dummy as
```

I want the regex to extract 'bar' and 'dummy', not 'foo whatever between bar' and 'dummy'

Comment: Regular expressions can't easily deal with nested structures, you need a recursive descent parser.

Comment: It's not clear what output should be. Please clarify.

Comment: Prepend your regex with `.*`

Comment: @Barmar is it possible to use negative look ahead ? I cannot make it work though.

Comment: No, negative lookahead won't help. I assume you allow arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: @revo that is brilliant, is it a clever way to make use of the greedy nature of regex ?

Comment: @Barmar yes but I think revo's answer is good to me. I am not really looking for nested structure extraction. I would write some parser for that.

Comment: I misunderstood what you were looking for until you posted the example.

Comment: Where is `as ...` in the example?

Comment: @Barmar at the end of the text. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend your regex with `.*` or use a negative lookahead:

```
between(?!.*between\b)\s+(.+?)\s+and\s+(.+?)\s+as
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vjkr0h/2)

Comment: This doesn't match the word `dummy`

Comment: Please check live demo. It does. @asdf

Comment: Eh, I'm not a fan of that lookahead. If the word "between" appears anywhere later in the string, your regex won't match anything. Like in `between x and y as between` -> no match. You should rewrite that to `(?:(?!between\b).)*`.

Comment: @revo, yes it does if the word as is prepended which it was not in the post, but it appears that is the context

Comment: Is it? I think it's about making the text matched by the first group as short as possible. If that's what the question is about, why would you suggest prepending `.*`? That does something completely different than your lookahead.

Comment: On given sample and same sample inputs prepending with `.*` or lookahead approach produces the same result to capturing groups. @Aran-Fey

Comment: I mean... the regex `(bar) and (dummy)` also works on the sample data, but that doesn't mean that it's a correct answer... The green checkmark seems to imply that your solution is what the OP wants, but I have a suspiction that it'll come back to bite them in the near future...

Comment: Yours doesn't follow a variable pattern so it couldn't fit as a solution. OP may have much more different formats within their input strings that I just can't imagine all of them. So I leave it for them to clear any time they faced an issue. @Aran-Fey

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your specific problem, you need to match the whitespace leading up to the between in question (which seems to be the limiting factor). I was able to achieve the results with the following:

```
^.+(\s)between\s(.+?)\sand\s(.+?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
between\s([^\s]+)\sand\s([^\s]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vjkr0h/5